# configuration.module.rules.loader should be a non-empty string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, loader

Upgraded my project to latest version and started facing this issue.

[image]

And here is my webpack code which I was using and working fine in older version.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.module\.s(a|c)ss$/,
            loader: [
                isDevelopment ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                        sourceMap: isDevelopment
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: isDevelopment
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
            exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
            loader: [
                isDevelopment ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: isDevelopment
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/'
                    }
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.mp3$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my package.json

[image]

All I did was updated my node to latest version ( 16.14.0 ) and updates all the dependency packages to their latest version. And after that my app broke.

Tried different approach, but still wouldn't able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Loader can now only be a string. "use" should be used for multiple loader values.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11418